# Is this function $f(x) = 2 - \Phi(a-x) - \Phi(a)$ log-concave?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis

I would like to verify this function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be log-concave or determine the region where it is:
$$
f(x) = 2 - \Phi(a-x) - \Phi(a)
$$
where $a > 0$ is a constant, and $\Phi(x) :=  \frac12\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] $, i.e. the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

1. My attempt is based on "[every concave function that is nonnegative
   on its domain is log-concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#Properties)".  $\Phi$ is convex over $(-\infty,
       0)$ (and concave over $(0,\infty)$), so $f$ is concave over $(a, \infty)$. Since $f$ is nonnegative,
   $f$ is log-concave over $(a, \infty)$. Am I right?
2. But I hope to decide if $f$ is log-concave over $\mathbb{R}$, or at
   least over $(0, \infty)$. Also is it possible
   to determine the region where $f$ is log-concave?
3. To simplify the question, if $f$ is log-concave, is $f + c$
   for any constant $c$ also log-concave?
4. I am also puzzled when trying to determine where g is log-concave,
   $$ g(x) := 1 - \Phi(a-x) + \Phi(-a-x) $$ and whether it is over $(0,
       \infty)$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Hello, could you check whether $g$ was log-concave?

Answer (score 2):

It certainly can't be log-concave over $\mathbb R$, because  $f$ has a positive limit $1 - \Phi(a)$ as $x \to -\infty$, and an increasing concave function can't have a finite limit at $-\infty$.

For $a=1$, numerical calculations show $\log f$ has an inflection at approximately $x=0.2180016571$, so it's not log-concave on $(0,\infty)$.

EDIT: here is a picture of part of the $a-x$ plane: $\log f$ is concave in the blue region and convex in the red region.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why "an increasing concave function can't have a limit at −∞"? I can visualize such a function that is a counterexample by converging to $-\infty$. Do you mean "log-concave" instead of "concave"?

Comment: No, I mean concave.  If $f'(x_0) > 0$ and the function is concave, $f(x) < f(x_0) + (x-x_0) f'(x_0) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: I meant a finite limit, of course.

Comment: Thanks! How did you generate the plot of the concave/convex regions? My way is quite stupid, but is the best I can think of: I can only plot the functions for several values of $a$.

Comment: I used the implicitplot function in Maple.